# Derivation of torsion in supergravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, supergravity

I am trying to derive the expression for torsion, equation (9.18), in the textbook Supergravity ( by Freedman and Proeyen, 2012 ). The strategy is to vary the Einstein-Hilbert action ( $S_2$ ) and the grivitino action ( $S_{3/2}$ ) with respect to the spin connection $\omega_\nu^{ab}$ and demand that it vanishes for EOM:

$$ \delta S_2 + \delta S_{3/2} = 0 \tag{9.17}$$

For the variation $\delta S_{3/2}$, one can use these two equations ( e is the determinant of vielbein ):
$$ \delta S_{3/2} = - \frac{1}{8 \kappa^2} \int d^D x\ e\ (\bar{\psi} _\mu \gamma ^{\mu\nu\rho} \gamma _{ab} \psi _\rho ) \delta \omega _\nu ^{ab} \tag{9.15} $$

$$ \bar{\psi} _\mu \gamma ^{\mu\nu\rho} \gamma _{ab} \psi _\rho = \bar{\psi} _\mu \left( \gamma ^{\mu\nu\rho} _{ab} + 6 \gamma ^{[\mu} e ^\nu _{[b} e ^{\rho]} _{a]}  \right) \psi _\rho \tag{9.16}$$

For the variation $\delta S_{2}$, we use:
$$ \delta S_2 = \frac{1}{2 \kappa^2} \int d^D x\ e\ ( T _{\rho a} ^{\ \ \rho} e _b ^\nu -  T _{\rho b} ^{\ \ \rho} e _a ^\nu + T _{ab} ^{\ \ \nu} ) \delta \omega _\nu ^{ab} \tag{8.52}$$

Now putting these two variations back in (9.17) gives us:
$$  T _{\rho a} ^{\ \ \rho} e _b ^\nu -  T _{\rho b} ^{\ \ \rho} e _a ^\nu + T _{ab} ^{\ \ \nu}   =  \frac{1}{4}\bar{\psi} _\mu  \gamma ^{\mu\nu\rho} _{\ \ \ \ \ ab} \psi _\rho +  \frac{3}{2} \bar{\psi} _\mu  \gamma ^{[\mu} e ^\nu _{[b} e ^{\rho]} _{a]}   \psi _\rho  \tag{A}$$

Then the authors get after simplification the final result:
$$ T _{a b} ^{\ \ \nu} = \frac{1}{4}\bar{\psi} _\mu  \gamma ^{\mu\nu\rho} _{\ \ \ \ \ ab} \psi _\rho +  \frac{1}{2} \bar{\psi} _a  \gamma ^\nu \psi _b  \tag{9.18}$$

I understand that the last term in (A) will turn into $\bar{\psi} _a  \gamma ^\nu \psi _b $ (upto a correct numerical factor ) using the antisymmetries and vielbein contractions.

Other than that, all I can infer is that $ T _{a b} ^{\ \ \nu}$ must be antisymmetric in indices a and b because all other terms in (A) are already antisymmetric in a and b. This will simplify the LHS of (A) slightly.(  The LHS will become $2T _{\rho a} ^{\ \ \rho} e _b ^\nu + T _{ab} ^{\ \ \nu}$ .) But I still don't understand how to get (9.18) from there. In particular, how do I kill the $2T _{\rho a} ^{\ \ \rho} e _b ^\nu$ term?

So my question is : **How to go from (A) to (9.18)?** Any hint will be appreciated.